# Don't allow droplist if there's any unchecked checkbox?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

I'm trying to solve this problem in Google Sheets. I have a Data Validation based droplist on column A (each row contains new droplist). I need it to be visible only when all of the checkboxes ABOVE it in column F are TRUE. If they are FALSE, then I need the A column droplist to be invisible/ blank. If user would select all checkboxes, the A column droplist would become visible again.

Example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12BlvudCrSFIGJI9s41mFOPqTRml4uLTQ4ODRtLKgBd0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please provide [mcve] so that we can reproduce your current issue.  You may also have to supply some markdown tables so that we can reproduce required data.

Comment: Here's an example of dynamic dropdowns being created on the fly. It's on my website [here](https://sites.google.com/view/googlappsscript/multiple-dependent-drop-downs) Scroll down to the bottom of the page and there is a live demo there.  You will notice that the drop down for dependant lists is not created until the previous selection is made.  So you could do something like that.

Comment: Sorry about this @Cooper / Here's an example with quick explanation: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12BlvudCrSFIGJI9s41mFOPqTRml4uLTQ4ODRtLKgBd0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: View only doesn't allow me to do much?

Answer (score 1):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast("Entry");
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.columnStart == 2 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    e.source.toast('Gate1');
    let arr = [...Array.from(new Array(e.range.rowStart).keys(),x => x)];
    if(arr.every(r => e.range.offset(-r,0).getValue() == true)) {
      //Logger.log(arr.map(r => e.range.offset(-r,0).getValue()));
      let rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().setAllowInvalid(false).requireValueInList(["A","B","C"]).build();
      sh.getRange(1,1,e.range.rowStart).clearDataValidations();
      sh.getRange(1,1,e.range.rowStart).setDataValidation(rule);
    }
  }
  if(sh.getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.columnStart == 2 && e.value == "FALSE") {
    e.source.toast('Gate2');
    let arr = [...Array.from(new Array(e.range.rowStart).keys(),x => x)];
    if(arr.some(r => e.range.offset(-r,0).getValue() == false)) {
      Logger.log(arr.map(r => e.range.offset(-r,0).getValue()));
      sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1).clearDataValidations().clearContent();;
    }
  }
}
```

Demo:

[image]

Comment: Lovely, that is almost exactly what I need, only thing different from this is that I need the dropdown not to appear if any upper checkbox is unchecked. I mean if let's say B1 is is checked, then A2 should be droplist, if B1 is unchecked, A2 should be blank (without droplist)

Comment: In other words - I need this checkbox to be checked, so a dropdown list would appear in the row below it.

Comment: I let you work out the logic for that because I don't fully understand what you want.  If you want to attempt it yourself you can and if you have difficulty then ask another question.

Comment: I understand, thank you anyway for your help, it brought me much closer to what I need, hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a non script-based approach. As per your example file:

- In A1:A4, change the data validation drop down range to D1:G4
- Retain tick boxes in B1:B4
- In D1, enter the formula `=arrayformula(ifna(if(match(FALSE,B1:B4,0)>row(B1:B4),na(),),{"ABC1","ABC2","ABC3","ABC4"}))`

This approach results in the validation range only being populated for each row if all checkboxes above that row are TRUE, so for any row which is FALSE the validation range is empty.